# How to assign string in a variable as a title for button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app i need to assign a string as a title for the uibutton.

How can i do this.For example

```
NSString *date=[[NSString alloc]initwithString:@"Todays Date"];
//am trying to assign the date content as a title for my button

[Button setTitle:date state:ForNormalSatate];
```

How can i set title as "Todays Date" for the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for setting a button title is:

`[myButton setTitle:date forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Or are you more interested in getting the date as a string ? Look up the documentation for `NSDateFormatter`. If you have trouble with it, search StackOverflow for it.

BTW 1: Don't forget to release your `date` string.

Comment: @iphoneStruggler: What exactly do you mean with "didn't succeed" ? Do you get an error message ? If yes, which ? If not, try to also set the button title for the most important other UIControlStates, like disabled and selected.

Comment: i didn't get any error but i didnt get what i want s a title  
[btnDate1 setTitle:date forState: UIControlStateNormal]; It is showing tittle as date but i want title as "Todats date"

Comment: Now *that's* a completely different beast :-) Please ask a new question, where you only concentrate on that point: *"How do I turn an NSDate into the string* Today *if it is today ?"*